# Composer Akeneo installation Could not open input file composer.phar

Tags: apache, docker, composer-php, symlink, akeneo

I am trying to install a PIM named Akeneo. The system requirements are all checked:
https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_requirements.html

I am on Apache2 / Ubuntu 16.04

My /var/**www**/ directory all belongs to www-data:www-data ( ran `chown -R www-data:www-data` to install )

Error message from server : “Could not open input file: composer.phar”

Googled about it , got many results,  and looked on the forums on stakoverflow, found answers from **2010** to 2018. I think I have maybe found out that the problem could be linked with the file "composer.phar", the way symlinks work on apache2, and composer installed globally or "inside individual project(s)".

Following 2 tutorials, I had to install composer to continue the install for that PIM.

My server says:

> Composer (version 1.10.10) successfully installed to:
> /usr/local/bin/composer

If I navigate to `cd ~` and run `ls` I see there is "composer.phar" and "composer-setup.php" here.

I am confused because the Akeno tutorial says:

> After extracting the file, change into the Akeneo directory and run
> the commands below:

```
cd /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard

sudo php -d memory_limit=3G ../composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist

sudo php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod

...
```

I don't understand the composer.phar install part . There are no `composer.phar` file inside any directories : not in  `/var/www/html/akeneo/` and not in  `/var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard`

Was it supposed to generate a composer.phar file there ?  Should it find composer.phar one level above ( ../composer.phar ) ? I doubled checked the Akeneo PIM files , and the original .rar archive has no composer.phar file. Or, is it something to do with a symlink that accesses the global "composer.phar" which was with the global install ? Regarding symlinks, there are some in the "vendor" fodler of the PIM, and  `runing ls -l -a` gives :

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   28 Feb  5  2020 doctrine -> ../doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   34 Feb  5  2020 doctrine-dbal -> ../doctrine/dbal/bin/doctrine-dbal
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   46 Feb  5  2020 doctrine-migrations -> ../doctrine/migrations/bin/doctrine-migrations
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   56 Feb  5  2020 requirements-checker -> ../symfony/requirements-checker/bin/requirements-checker
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   51 Feb  5  2020 var-dump-server -> ../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/bin/var-dump-server
```

There is a `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file inside /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard . So confused because the turorial says to be inside pim-community-standard directory and run this : `php -d memory_limit=3G ../composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist`

I hope I can resume the install without breaking anything. Some posts give the solution of updating composer, or installing composer-phar, inside the project. I am honestly totally lost.

( I don't know if I should bring that up, but is docker needed (not talked about in tutorial - but I see a folder with "docker" in it and I know that composer and docker can work together sometimes )

Comment: `composer.phar` is a **ph**p **ar**chive containing the php source code needed to run [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). This can actually be installed anywhere on your system as long as you have access to it.

Comment: Akeneo PIM offers an installation with docker which will probably be more suited to you. And you should use the latest stable version (4.0) and the correct docs (2.3 is not maintained for a long time)

Comment: How is this related to Apache or Docker? Please do not use irrelevant tas. Also, if the command uses `composer.phar` at some place where it does not exist, why not reference the proper path of `composer.phar`?

Comment: @Pierre Thanks for the tip, yea I will try with Docker on my next attempt. In the end I had to give up because of some problem to create elastic search index I believe, inside parameters.yml for the line about index_hosts: nothing works, not 'elastic:changeme@localhost:9200' or 'elastic:changeme@localhost:80' or 'localhost:80' or '127.0.0.1:80' or 'localhost:9200' or '127.0.0.1:9200 or '127.0.0.1:9200 or '155.231.133.211:9200' or  '155.231.133.211:80' .I will try Akeneo with Docker later and I just use a temporary solution for what I wanted to to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the composer.phar file into the app directory. Now the install advanced. It's not a technical issue a misconfiguration or anything like that.

It's a lack of information about Composer on the Akeneo site but it's probably assumed that users should have knowledge about Composer allready.

Solution for me : moving the "composer.phar" file (from 'home' for me ) to the /var/www/project/  (.. the correct level  directory).

So for my case it was a global / local install issue , which is still unclear, and I will have to look deeper how to properly install composer. Not sure if my current setup will not cause any issue later since it's like I installed it globally at first then moved only one file.

Also, command "composer" is not returning anything. I do have the composer file in /usr/bin/ though. This is very strange.